# Laravel URL Helper return IP address instead of Domain name

Tags: laravel, apache

I have a problem when trying to create the Url using URL helper. I'm using Laravel 6.

`$verify_url = url("/verify");`

This is return the URL with the IP address instead of the domain name.

I don't know if it is a problem with the Apache server or the code.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: did you solve the problem . i m stucked on same thing

Answer (score 1):

Adding this directive to Apache Virtual Host config seems to have fixed it: `ProxyPreserveHost On`

But a better way to use your urls is to name them in your **routes/web.php**. For ex:

```
Route::post('/verify', 'HomeController@verify')->name('verify');
```

and wherever you need to access to this url just use like this:

```
$verify_url = route('verify');
```